# Javascript touch event doesn't fire in portrait orientation

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, orientation, touch-event

I'm making a web-app where you can move elements around on a canvas and draw lines between them. Everything works as expected when in `landscape` mode on iphone and ipad, but when I switch into `portrait` mode touch will not be fired in the footer.

It is only in the footer part the touch doesn't respond. And if I move the "button" up or make the footer height larger it will work but it makes the design look awful. The footer has a fixed position at the bottom. I've tried with different ipads/iphones and iOs-version (iPad2:iOs 9.0.2, iPhone6:iOS 9.0.1, iPad 4th gen: iOS 9.0.2, etc).

This is really driving me crazy. What am I missing? Why will it work in landscape orientation and not in portrait? Anybody got a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there is another element covering the footer section. You can try checking it out on Google chrome, toggling the device mode to iphone in portrait mode and inspecting the elements on the page.

Comment: I tried it (didn't have Chrome on my computer, but downloaded it and it  is great for testing so I will definitely use it more in future so thanks for this great suggestion!). However, the app works as should in Chrome simulating iphone 6 in portrait mode, but on real device it will still fail...